# "swscanf" not parsing the string till $ sign

Tags: c++, scanf

I have below snippet. I am expecting swscanf to remove $ sign from string ".exe$" and copy only .exe to the destination. But it is always copying ".exe$"

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t name[10];

    swscanf(L".exe$", L"%ls$", name);
    std::wcout<<wstring(name)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `%ls` you are telling it to consume as many wide characters as it can. The `$` sign afterwards is ignored.

What you want instead is to tell it to scan any wide character except the `$` sign. So replace `s`with `[^$]`:

```
swscanf(L".exe$", L"%l[^$]", name);
```

Comment: Thank you Max. what if the string name is wchar_t, can I use %ws? How it goes if I want to use ws?

Comment: @RashmiRamanna What do you mean? Your example and my answer use `wchar_t` already.